# Keras model.evaluate() print vector of loss values

Tags: python, keras

Using `model.evaluate()` prints the mean loss over the test set. Is it possible to instead get out a vector off loss values for all data points in the test set (the average of which would then be what is printed by `model.evaluate()`)?

Comment: Was my answer what you were trying to do? If so please accept my answer, otherwise let me know if you wanted something else.

Answer (score 1):

As a built-in function, the loss is usually more useful as the average so that you can do different visualizations. As for getting the results, just compute them yourself and you will be set. For example

```
def squared_error(y_true, y_pred):
    return tf.math.square(y_true - y_pred)

predictions = model.predict(x_test)
losses = squared_error(y_test, predictions)
```

Alternatively, it may be doable using built in loss functions with a batch size of 1 like this

```
loss_fn = tf.keras.losses.mse
# x_test should be (batches, your_dims) where you make sure each batch only has 1 sample
predictions = model.predict(x_test)
losses = loss_fn(y_test, predictions)
```